# How do I convert this batch file to a .REG file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-registry

As the title reads I am trying to convert the following .bat file to a .reg file instead as the application does not support the current file type.

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\SysTray" /v "Services" /t reg_dword /d 29 /fsystray
```

So far I have the following but am stuck:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\SysTray]
"Services"=dword:0000000
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just export the key using Regedit.

Comment: Or look at an exported key and use the same convention.

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik
Yes, this was a stupid simple solution. Not sure why I didn't think of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could run the your command and seamlessly export it to your desired reg file...

[image]

However, your command contains additional strings that result in not executing the entry of items/values....

```
> reg add add ... /fsystray  
  ERROR: Invalid syntax.
  Type "REG ADD /?" for usage.
  
> rem :: ??? /f[systray] 
> rem :: should be just /f  
  
> reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\SysTray" /v "Services" /t reg_dword /d 29 /f
  The operation completed successfully.
```

---

- Reg_Add.Reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\SysTray]
"Services"=dword:0000001d
```

---

- Optional hybrid .Reg +.Bat

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;@(cls & %__AppDir__%reg.exe import "%~f0" & goto :eof)
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\SysTray]
"Services"=dword:0000001d
```

**Obs.:** Save YourFile.bat or YourFile.cmd:

---

**[hide or remove safely remove hardware tray icon](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/hide-or-remove-safely-remove-hardware-tray-icon/)**

About the `systray` in your command:

The string is an additional command in bat available in the link above.
where one line is the `reg add... /f` and on the next line the `systray` command, and somehow, the two lines come together creating a command that returns an error, maybe for this reason you look for a `.reg` file for to do the same action...

> - ***[`hide-safely-remove-hardware.bat`](https://raymondcc.r.worldssl.net/hide-safely-remove-hardware.bat)***
>
> ```
> reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\SysTray" /v "Services" /t reg_dword /d 29 /f
> systray
> ```