# Batch file running installation through intune

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, windows-registry, intune

I have created a batch file that  will run an installation through intune.

1. it will install the application
2. it will install the configuration file

And I need to add a 3rd step, which would then add a registry key once step 1 and 2 are completed.

Current batch file:

```
application.exe /quiet /norestart 
timeout /t 50 /nobreak
"C:\Program Files\Fortinet\FortiClient\config.exe" -m all -f ".\config.conf" -o import -i 1 -p XX
```

How do I go about adding the registry in same batch?

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Fortinet\FortiClient\FA_UI\VPN-7.2]
"installed"=dword:651dce3a
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally disagree with the great @DavidPostill !! :^P

I suggest (if you are already in batch) using the `reg` command and not a .reg file as the legend himself suggests.

Something like:
`reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\SOFTWARE\Fortinet\FortiClient\FA_UI\VPN-7.2 /v installed /t REG_DWORD /d 651dce3a`

Try `reg /?` from the command line to see the options.

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I go about adding the registry in the same batch file?

Use `regedit`:

> Import a reg script:
>
> ```
> REGEDIT pathname
> ```

where `pathname` is the name of the file containing the instructions.

Example:

```
regedit myfile.reg
```

where `myfile.reg` contains:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Fortinet\FortiClient\FA_UI\VPN-7.2]
"installed"=dword:651dce3a
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [regedit](http://ss64.com/nt/regedit.html) - Import, export or delete registry settings from a text (.REG) file.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 ; & @cls & @cd /d "dp0" & @goto :install

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Fortinet\FortiClient\FA_UI\VPN-7.2]
"installed"=dword:651dce3a

;:install
;   @;( 
;      %ComSpec% /c "start "" /w "application.exe" /quiet /norestart"
;      %ComSpec% /c "start "" /w "C:\Program Files\Fortinet\FortiClient\config.exe" -m all -f ".\config.conf" -o import -i 1 -p XX"
;      "%__AppDir__%reg.exe" import "%~f0" 1>nul 2>&1
;    );=
```

---

**1.** Use a **[hybrid](https://superuser.com/a/1675260/969781)** **[batch](/questions/tagged/batch)** with **[reg](/questions/tagged/reg)** file;

**2.** Use `cmd.exe "Start /Wait .."` your installers/configurator;

**3.** Save the above code as some file **`Name.cmd`** and run...

**P.S.**  **`Start /wait ..`** replaces your **`timeout 50`** to a precise time